# Using added account in VSTO Outlook add-in before restart

Tags: c++, vsto, outlook-addin, mapi

We are developing a VSTO Outlook add-in and need to get an added account on the same Outlook run, not after restart. In C# properties it is not available.

Using MAPI in C++ DLL we can get the accounts, but we also need StoreID. When we request the property using

```
hRes = lpAccount->GetProp(PROP_ACCT_DELIVERY_STORE, &pProp);
```

it does not get success before restart of Outlook. The other properties work normally. Maybe it is an issue with a kind of cache, but we did not find any cache update methods in Microsoft documentation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you add the account? What kind of account is it? can you see that property in OutlookSpy (click IOlkAccountManager)?

Comment: I add the account using Mail in Control Panel. It is a simple IMAP account with autodiscover addition. When I use OutlookSpy, the old account have properties PROP_ACCT_DELIVERY_STORE and PROP_ACCT_DELIVERY_FOLDER, but the new one does not.

Comment: If Outlook is running, it probably won't populate those fields (and create the OST file) until you actually use that account, e.g., by expanding its root folder

Comment: No, I tried using this account, the Inbox contains test messages, but still OutlookSpy does not show that properties, and the registry does not contain such keys.

Comment: We tried to use PROP_ACCT_IMAP_SENTITEMS_STORE and get success.

Comment: There is a hope to use PROP_ACCT_SENTITEMS_EID which is documented and then search this EntryID over all Stores.

Comment: Why do you need to search? You can try to open the folder using `IMAPISession::OpenEntry` (it will succeed as long as the store was touched at least once in the current session) and then retrieve the store entry id (`PR_STORE_ENTRYID`) from the `IMAPIFolder` object.

Comment: Thanks for `IMAPISession::OpenEntry`, will try.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko please, help, `GetProp()` of `PROP_ACCT_SENTITEMS_EID` gives `E_NOTIMPL` result in our code, while your OutlookSpy gives the value. Is there a trick when calling `GetProp()`? No help of Google.

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't know. How do you open the account object?

Comment: The code here: https://pastebin.com/YveM0JnK The session may be from C# MAPIOBJECT, and may be opened in C++, the same thing.

Comment: Do you run that code immediately after adding the account? Or at some later point after Outlook was idle?

Comment: Are you sure PROP_ACCT_SENTITEMS_EID is correctly defined in your code?

Comment: That code is run firstly on existing account, it does not get the property.
The definition:
`#define PROP_ACCT_SENTITEMS_EID   PROP_TAG(PT_BINARY, 0x0020)`
Seems to be OK.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the `ACCT_INIT_NOSYNCH_MAPI_ACCTS` flag?

Comment: No change when use `OLK_ACCOUNT_NO_FLAGS`

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know. As a test, can you try if RDOIMAPAccount.SaveSentMessageFolder in Redemption exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: Strange thing. Once StoreID from `RDOIMAPAccount.SaveSentMessageFolder` got result with new account, but the other times it gives exception `Error in IMsgStore.OpenEntry: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`. When using Dynamic View the Account object gives exception on this field. The old account works properly. The `[Account].Store.EntryID` works properly in all cases. The code: https://pastebin.com/YWxMZ1Fm

Comment: Does the code actually run? It assumes you only have RDOIMAPAccount accounts in the profile.

Comment: I have: one stable IMAP account and one IMAP account for add/remove in test environment, that is all. This code has been run, yes.

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't know. Just to make sure, all of this is done before the new IMAP4 store in opened in Outlook, right? Or is it after you open and expand the new IMAP4 store in Outlook?

Comment: It is after I open the account and it's folders in Outlook interface.